# Read csv data into R (read.csv)

Tags: read.csv, working-directory

I want to read in a csv (excel) file in my R file.
Usually I use read.csv but this time it does not work can anybody help me?
My code:
persons <- read.csv("persons.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",")

Console gives out:
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
cannot open file 'persons.csv': No such file or directory

I read that this can happen if my working directory is not right. So I checked:
getwd()
Console: [1] "/Users/annemass"

How do I know that my file is in this working directory (Im working currently on a macbook of a friend of mine and struggling a little bit with it)

Also I tried:
persons <- file.choose()
persons
Console: [1] "/Users/annemass/Desktop/persons.csv"

So it was possible to select the file. Does this mean I am in the right working directory?
Problem still is that it does not import the file it just saves the path to the file.

Hope someone could help me. Im new to this and do not really get the working directory thing.

Greeting and thank you in advanced
Mario Francesco

Answer (score 0):

so I found a solution that is:
persons <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = FALSE, sep = ",")

but with read.csv("persons.csv") it still does not work.